# Adding a style to a class defined in a custom UI library

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Currently I am working on a UI Library which is supposed to contain custom UI Elements, Layouts and Dialogs in order to have a consistent and reusable UI collection.

In my project, the current structure is as follows:

- UILib (Shared Code for the library)
- UILib.Droid (android library containing custom renders, etc.)
- UILib.iOS (iOS library containing custom renderers, etc.)
- UILibDemo (Shared Code for demo application consuming the library)
- UILibDemo.Droid (demo application Android)
- UILibDemo.iOS (demo application iOS)

In my library I have a class "LoadingDialog", which works fine so far.
However my problem is that I am now trying to define a style to change some properties of the LoadingDialog from within the shared code of the demo application (App.xaml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:dialogs="clr-namespace:UILib.Dialogs;assembly=UILib"
         x:Class="BetterUIDemo.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="DefaultFontLight">OpenSans-Light.ttf</x:String>
        <Color x:Key="ThemeColor">#f08c00</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#37474f</Color>

        <Style x:Key="LoadingDialogStyle" TargetType="dialogs:LoadingDialog">
            <Setter Property="ThrobberBackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="LabelFontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFontLight}" />
            <Setter Property="LabelColor" Value="{DynamicResource ThemeColor}" />
            <Setter Property="LoadingText" Value="Lade Daten ..." />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My LoadingDialog class contains these properties as well:

```
#region Properties
    public static BindableProperty ThrobberBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ThrobberBackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Color), Color.Black);
    public static BindableProperty FontFamilyProperty = BindableProperty.Create("FontFamily", typeof(string), typeof(string), Font.Default.FontFamily);
    public static BindableProperty LabelColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Color), Color.Black);
    public static BindableProperty LoadingTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LoadingText", typeof(string), typeof(string), "Loading ...");

    public string LabelFontFamily
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color ThrobberBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ThrobberBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThrobberBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public string LoadingText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LoadingTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadingTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color LabelColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LabelColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelColorProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion
```

However when I try to compile the demo app, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Position 14:13. Can't resolve LabelFontFamily on LoadingDialog  UILibDemo   C:\Work\UILib\UILibDemo\UILibDemo\App.xaml  14

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could just be a naming thing causing your error.

Bindable Properties use some "Magic" where the `Property name` and the `bindable property` need to be named the same thing but the bindable property has the word **Property** on the end

Notice how your `BindableProperty` is just called `FontFamily`

Changing it to the below should fix your error

```
public static BindableProperty LabelFontFamilyProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelFontFamily", typeof(string), typeof(string), Font.Default.FontFamily);

public string LabelFontFamily
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
   set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just found it myself. Sometimes it is the little things.
+1 for the added explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. For further reference:

The issue was a mismatch between the BindableProperty registered as "FontFamily" and the actual property

```
public string LabelFontFamily
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
}
```

Changing the property to

> public string FontFamily

resolved the issue.